# Is there a clean way to mix asyncronous and syncronous database query processing?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am finding that syncronous database queries generate [`mozIStorageStatementRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/mozIStorageStatementRow) whereas asyncronous code generates [`mozIStorageRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/MozIStorageRow).

I can easily work around this via a simple Shim.  Is there a cleaner (i.e., cleaner than my shim) way to pass around database query results when working with a mix of syncronous and asyncronous calls?

Example code, starting from a `mozIStorageStatement` (e.g., by calling [`createStatement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/mozIStorageConnection#createStatement%28%29)):

```
//Sync Example:
    myStorageStatement.executeStep();   
    var row = myStorageStatement.row;
    var myNameColumn = row.name;

//Sync Shim Example:
    myStorageStatement.executeStep();
    var row = {
        getResultByName: function (str) {
            return myStorageStatement.row[str];
        }
    };
    var myNameColumn = row.getResultByName("name");

//ASync Example:
    myStorageStatement.executeAsync({
        //...
        handleResult: function (aResultSet) {
            var row = aResultSet.getNextRow();
            var myNameColumn = row.getResultByName("name");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware off (and I read the actual code a couple of times in the past)...

Both `mozIStorageStatement` (not `..Row`), and `mozIStorageRow` also implement [`mozIStorageValueArray`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/storage/public/mozIStorageValueArray.idl), which is a bit more low-level. Make sure to `QueryInterface`/`instanceof` as required.

Other than that you'll have to write some wrapper or [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), like you already did.

*Aside*: You should avoid the synchronous API, if possible, in order to keep the main (UI) thread snappy. IIRC there are even plans (or at least were) to remove it in the long term. There is also a high-level wrapper called [`Sqlite.jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Sqlite.jsm), especially when used in conjunction with `Task.jsm` (examples on the `Sqlite.jsm` page).

Comment: Alas, I am required to support Firefox 4.0, so no Sqlite.jsm for me.  Using a proxy is probably less of a headache than working with mozIStorageValueArray, but thank you for pointing it out.  As for moving away from the synchronous API, I've been doing so over time.  There are a few places where synchronous calls are probably safer (due to similar extensions hooking on the same events as my own, then both extensions having their decisions influenced by each other's actions).

Comment: That's too bad. Even mozilla does not support Firefox 4 anymore... for quite some time actually. ;) But yeah, I see your point. I try to support the latest ESR at least, in most of my stuff.

Comment: Cutting off support for 4.0 wouldn't be completely impossible; not that many people are using it.  If I encountered a particularly useful feature, I might propose cutting off support for lower versions.  However, Sqlite.jsm doesn't really qualify; not only is it not wonderful enough but also we still have a lot of users on FF19-.  And Task.jsm et. al isn't that exciting; I've recently started using RSVP and that's already a huge step up.